# Не обновляются данные rcAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Вот код:

```
    package com.example.hondle.biling.fragments;

public class contracts extends Fragment {
    public final String TAG = "contracts";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    CatTask cattask;

    RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter;
    RecyclerView rView;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    private LinearLayoutManager lLayout;

    public String[] contractId = new String[100];

    public static contracts newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        contracts fragment = new contracts();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }


    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contracts, container, false);

        Log.d(TAG, "Start");

        cattask = new CatTask();
        cattask.execute();

        List<ItemObject> rowListItem = getAllItemList();
        lLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        rView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);

        rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), rowListItem);
        rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    private List<ItemObject> getAllItemList(){

        List<ItemObject> allItems = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();

        allItems.add(new ItemObject(contractId[0], "6"));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject(contractId[1], "2"));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Ближайший офис", "3"));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Заказать звонок", "4"));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Позвонить в контактный центр", "5"));

        return allItems;
    }

    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
    class CatTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        public String token = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("access_token");
        TextView text;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.d(TAG, "start");
            Log.d(TAG, token);


            String token = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("access_token");
            Log.d(TAG, token);
            DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            ResponseHandler GetResponse = new BasicResponseHandler();
            HttpGet http = new HttpGet("mysite.openregion.info/api/v1.3.0/contract/getlist?access_token=" + token);

            try {

                String response = (String) hc.execute(http, GetResponse);
                Log.d(TAG, response);

                JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray contracts = jobj.getJSONArray("contracts");
                String contract = contracts.getString(0);

                for (int i = 0; i < contracts.length(); i++) {
                    contractId[i] = String.valueOf(contracts.get(i));
                    HttpGet http2 = new HttpGet("mysite.info/api/v1.3.0/contract/counters?contract_id=" + contract);
                    Log.d(TAG, contractId[i]);

                    try {

                        String Cresponse = (String) hc.execute(http2, GetResponse);
                        Log.d(TAG, Cresponse);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            rcAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }
}
```

Вроде бы все работает, логирование показывает что все нормальное, но на экране данные не обновляются.

Comment: Вы данные в адаптере так и не обновили. Вы только какой-то массив строк переделали и всё. И не вываливайте весь код. Интерфейсы из вашего класса к делу не относятся и ухудшают читаемость кода. Облегчайте задачу отвечающим или их вообще не будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Вы данные в адаптере так и не обновили. Вы только какой-то массив строк переделали и всё. И не вываливайте весь код. Интерфейсы из вашего класса к делу не относятся и ухудшают читаемость кода. Облегчайте задачу отвечающим или их вообще не будет.– ЮрийСПб

Да вы правы были, я назначил применять адаптер, после выполнения AsyncTask и все заработала, как по маслу.